# Which local download version of CiviCRM is most like the Spark and what aspects of Spark can be customized?

Tags: civicrm-spark

Is there is a download version CiviCRM that is close to the Spark version. I would like to download it first locally and get comfortable with it then try Spark.

Also I think that the Admin functionality is available for tweaking some stuff but I also think there is a limited number of extensions available at this point. For instance can I add new or rename variables and menu items?

How about creating web page forms for embedding in a website such as a WordPress or Drupal CMS? I know it uses Drupal but still learning about running CiviCRM stand alone and then integrating with a CMS. I personally believe Drupal integration would best long term but might need to integrate with an Existing WordPress site for now. That is if the Spark version even allows integration with a CMS.

Thanks,
  Carl

Answer (score 1):

Spark is identical to the version of CiviCRM you would download, except that a) you can't install new extensions (it comes with iATS, PayPal, Shoreditch and Mosaico if I recall).  You're also limited in the number of contacts you can have.

Note that a "local" copy is a bit misleading in that you need to run a webserver to use CiviCRM.  While you could theoretically do this locally, it's requires tech chops - and if you have the capability to set up a local server, you probably don't need Spark.

Spark supports embedding basic web page forms in a separate CMS - but those forms are quite basic and can't take payments.  Payment forms will exist in the Spark install.  When discussing "CMS Integration" with CiviCRM, you're generally discussing options that are only available when installing CiviCRM within the CMS you're integrating with.

Comment: Thanks for reply & I see CiviCRM has a great community. I've installed it local using Bitnami/MAMP & will try adding Shoreditch

I am exploring dmaster.demo.civicrm.org which is like my local installation plus:
-Campaigns
-Grants
-Volunteers

Both local & demo seem integrated w/Drupal which I like but an existing Wordpress site may dictate choice of CMS

I'm exploring admin & customize features, most importantly how to integrate Contribution & other forms into a CMS - which I believe easier with Drupal integration than Wordpress.

Eventually I'll use Spark if it is the right fit.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting dropping the newlines. I think I have had this issue before using Chrome. I will try using another browser.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to download it first locally and get comfortable with it
>   then try Spark.

The idea behind Spark is the reverse!  You can get started quickly and easily with CiviCRM using Spark and experiment with what it can do, albeit with some restrictions.  From there, you could choose to continue with Spark or select a different hosting option - either hosted or local.

I don't think there is a specific download available matching the Spark configuration, but the latest release plus Shoreditch gives you a similar view.

There are also several demo sites around if you just want to experiment, although they are public and regularly reset.  See https://civicrm.org/demo

Comment: Thanks Aidan for your reply. Please see my comment below rather then me repeating that info.
Best
  Carl